# Update close vote privilege text

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, help-center

On https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions, there's the following paragraph (emphasis mine):

> Closed questions can also eventually be merged with another question, migrated to another site in our network, or even deleted. A closed question **can be deleted as early as 48 hours** after its initial closure.

Should this be amended somehow? I'm not sure how much detail it needs to include, but at the moment it's not technically correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A (non-spam) question can be deleted by the community, theoretically, the second it's closed, or at any time in the future. It can be deleted automagically at various times after closure. Further votes on the question can alter the automatic deletion timescales, so there's really no way to be certain at what point after closure a question may be deleted (if ever).

In other words, the sentence needs to be more ambiguous.

> A closed question may be deleted automatically, or by the community.

This reduces logically to what has just been stated.

> Closed questions can [...] be [...] deleted.

The entire sentence is redundant; it should be removed. There's also a small politeness gap between *"even be deleted"* and what I suggested initially. It's better to be polite...

Personally, I don't like the preceding sentence either; there's no need for "also"  and "eventually" makes it appear as though it might take a long time. Why not reword the entire thing to something like:

> Closed questions can be merged with another question, migrated to another site in our network, or even deleted.

Comment: Making it more ambiguous makes sense to me - it's not really the page to go into all the criteria of deletion. It might be an idea for *even deleted* to be hyper linked to a canonical MSO (or MSE) post/FAQ/help article that does explain it in detail - if only for completeness sake...

Comment: I updated the text to something very close to what you suggested: "Closed questions may be merged with another question, migrated to another site in our network, or even deleted."

Comment: Thanks Ben and @Laura - my inner pedant can rest for a while :p

Comment: Don't be ridiculous @Jon, if you have an inner pedant it's always awake and searching!